What can be passed as Program Arguments or VM options in Idea IntelliJ to run multiple tags?
I have something like this -
@scen1
Scenario: Missing product description
Given hello
@scen2
Scenario: Several products
Given hello
@scen3
Scenario: Expired products
Given hello
I have tried below in Program Args and VM options in the Run/Debug Configurations but nothing seems to work
-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@scen1 or @scen2'"
-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@scen1 or @scen2"
I want to run both scen1 and scen2
